# transform non-equivalence: not(A<->B) with de morgan

Tags: logic

I have the following non-equivalence:

```
not(A <-> B)
```

With a truth-table we can easily see that we have an XOR here:

```
(A and notB) or (notA and B)
```

But If I want to come to this conclusion by applying de morgan to not(A <-> B) I always get a wrong result. For me it is no problem to apply de morgan e.g. to

```
(A <-> B)
```

But I never get the right result when I try it on this:

```
 not(A <-> B)
```

Maybe someone has got a tip for me how this could be done with de morgan.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(A <-> B) <-> (A -> B && B -> A)`

`(Z -> Y) <-> (^Z || Y)`

hence

`^(A -> B && B -> A) <-> ^( (^A || B) && (^B || A))`

hence

`^(A <-> B) <-> ( ^(^A || B) || ^(^B || A))`

`^(A <-> B) <-> ( (A && ^B) || (^A && B) )`

`^(A <-> B) <-> A XOR B`

Where is the problem in that ?